# How can I set up a soil-free terrarium in a fish bowl?

Tags: watering, hydroponic, terrarium, fountain

I have an unused fish bowl lying around. I am keen on building a terrarium, which can include pebbles, rocks and other 'macro-stones' if you will, but not soil. I personally find soil quite icky to work with, and am a bit of a cleanliness freak.
At the same time, I would like to add a water feature like a water fall and I have a pump for this.
I have a lot of soil based plants at home, a lot for an apartment that size, and it can get challenging to keep on top of them. Hence, some maintenance free plants are something i look forward to.

All inputs are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What size "bowl". M y son has a 100 gal terrarium that does well.

Answer (score 0):

Aloe Vera, succulents in general and orchids (epiphytes) come to mind.

> Types of Plants That Don’t Need Soil
>
> 1. Snake Plants
> 2. Air Plants
> 3. Peace Lilies
> 4. Swiss Cheese Plants
> 5. English Ivies
> 6. Lucky Bamboos
> 7. Aloe Veras
> 8. Zanzibar Gems
> 9. Spider Plant
> 10. Money Plants
> 11. Marimo Moss Balls

From [11 Plants That Don’t Need Soil: Awesome Plants Without Dirt](https://www.evergreenseeds.com/plants-that-dont-need-soil/)

There is another list here [15 Plants that Grow Without Soil](https://gardentipsforall.com/plants-that-grow-without-soil/), **lucky bamboo** looks good for your scenario.